What mnemonic helps differentiate 瑞士 (Switzerland) from 瑞典 (Sweden)?
I get 瑞士 (Switzerland) from 瑞典 (Sweden) mixed up in Chinese, because they both start with 瑞.  Maybe you can help me...
Question: What mnemonic helps differentiate 瑞士 (Switzerland) from 瑞典 (Sweden)?

If you are just interested in the spelling, of course there is the Swiss flag in 瑞士...

@StephanKolassa The swedish flag also has a cross in it.

@Sören: but the aspect ratio is different!

They're both transcriptions of foreign language names.

瑞士 (~shì) is an approximation of Swiss, the adjective form of Switzerland;
瑞典 (~diǎn) is an approximation of Sweden.


Note that the first character was originally pronounced as an old Mandarin equivalent of shuì. Although you're not supposed to pronounce it as such, Shuìshì would be a rather close approximation of Swiss. See How was Switzerland transliterated into Chinese?.

It is vastly more likely to be a transliteration of the French noun Suisse than the English adjective Swiss.

@BrianChandler Yes, I skipped a few extraneous details and maybe portrayed it too simplistically to the point of being slightly wrong. The direct origin is like from French Suisse, but English Swiss also came from French Suisse.

I'm not sure if it helps since I'm coming from studying Japanese, but 士 looks very similar to 土 which I know as soil, earth. So I would remember that SwitzerLAND ends in a character that looks like one that means land. (As long as that doesn't cause you to get 士 and 土 mixed up -- they only look similar!)

If you want a "botched" Chinglish mnemonic, how about, Sweden is "Radiant" and the Swiss are "rushers"?

I don’t know Chinese, but 士 resembles a cross, similar to the one on the Swiss flag. If you already know 瑞 it should be very easy to remember that way
